# WordPress site isn't working after I migrated site - changed site address (URL)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I migrated from my local computer to my live server using Duplicator. When I switched over, my Wordpress Address (URL) was http://107.343.442.344 - my IP address - and the Site Address (URL) was http://nameofwebsite.com.  Everything appears to be working just fine.

However, when I add an item to my cart and try to delete it, it doesn't remove the item. I check the console and there's a failed AJAX request. It's requesting information from http://107.343.442.344.  So, I change the Site URL to http://107.343.442.344 and then the everything works just fine. However, now I can't go to my front page.

I tried making these changes to the database (WP-Options), but nothing works.

Does anyone know what I can do to correct the problem. I've contacted WooCommerce, but they're taking forever.

My site is not currently up, so you can't go to it.

Comment: I think it's related to db and that's why Woocommerce is requesting file from your local site. Please check my answer below where I explained how to properly migrate site from localhost to webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way how to properly migrate your site from localhost to server:

1. Copy all your local site files to web server
2. Install and activate "WP Migrate DB" plugin to your local site, it's free and got all functionality you will need.

After "WP Migrate DB" activation you will find it under "Tools" > "Migrate DB". Open "Migrate DB", there will be empty "Replace" block with two fields which you need to fill (look at the picture below).

[image]

These two fields are only one you need to fill, after that click on "Export" button and plugin will download mysql database.

3. Login into your hosting cPanel (or any other webhosting management app if your hosting doesn't provide cPanel, for example, ISPconfig etc.) and create new database or replace old one with that which you just created with "WP Migrate DB" plugin.
4. Open and edit wp-config.php file on your public_html folder on webserver, replacing database name and other authentification credentials (change database name, database user and password which you created in cPanel) and save this file.
5. Done, enjoy. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of this up. I'm going to give it a try as soon as I get home from work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you database is not migrate properly please try again with wp migrate db plugin or search replace file , if problem still appear then check the serve file and folder permissions

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was. I was using VHS Host to redirect the IP address to my new server. Once I changed the nameservers to point towards my new server, it worked.

Thanks to everyone who posted a response. I really do appreciate it.